# Styles not updating in chrome for android on jquery class change

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, google-chrome

Is there any reason why a changed class would not apply styles right away in Chrome for Android?

I have a Jquery web application that toggles whether or not an LI element is "accounted for" on click, changes the LI to green, and executes some calculations.  In every browser for desktop, and in Chrome for iOS, it applies the green style as expected.  But, in Chrome for Android, the styles are not applied.

I hooked up my phone to Chrome's handy device inspector, and the class IS being applied, just the styles are missing.  It completes the rest of the function, there's no javascript error, I've checked everything I know to be common issues.

The listener that fires the function looks like this

```
self.$(".thumbnail").unbind("click").click(function () {
    self.$(this).parent("li").toggleClass("accounted");
    calculateNumbers(true);
});
```

And the CSS looks like

```
.accounted {
    background: #9ADEA3 url("../img/diag-lines.png") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}
```

The same problem does not occur in Firefox for Android, so it looks like it's specific to Chrome for Android.

Any help?

Comment: can you post your js and css code?

Comment: You should include your code, otherwise everything that we say will be pure conjecture. However, my first guess would be specificity.

Comment: `important!` might help(Not the best way though)! But as stated in previous comments, Do post your code!

Comment: $(" .thumbnail").unbind("click").click(function () {
    self.$(this).parent("li").toggleClass("accounted");
    calculateNumbers(true);
});

That's the event listener that handles the toggle.